# Showing a complex sum $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n/n^s$ converges for $\Re(s)>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

The conditions on $a_n$ is that it is real and sums $a_1+....+a_n$ are bounded independently of $n$. I am given a hint that I should instead consider the sum
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}(a_1+.....+a_n)(1/n^s-1/(n+1)^s) $$

I am not clear on why this hint is given, as it seems to overcomplicate things.

Comment: If $a_1 + ... + a_n$ can be bounded independently of $n$, so can the individual terms $a_n$.

Comment: Maybe they thought of proving convergence [for $\Re s > 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743224/how-to-show-that-this-complex-series-converge)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed, Daniel. Convergence then follows from Dirichlet's Test.

Comment: @Joanpemo The abscissa of absolute convergence can still be $1$, and for $\Re s > 1$, we have a simpler argument for absolute convergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, indeed.

Comment: @Joanpemo : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: and Qbert what are you doing with Hadamard theorem ? it is for power series, not Dirichlet series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series . so please, prove the Hadamard theorem  for power series first, or you won't go anywhere in complex analysis.

Comment: @AlexR. : bounded means $|\sum_{k=1}^n a_n| < C$, otherwise we cannot say if it converges at all, since $a_n = -e^n$ would make the Dirichlet series diverging everywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40472/discussion-between-qbert-and-user1952009).

Comment: @user1952009 It's ok, I appreciate the help you have given. my confusion arose from the use of the nth root test for convergence of power series (like the ratio test) in real analysis, but I see that this works only for positive term series.

Comment: so I'm sorry that you didn't like some of my comments. For the proof of Hadamard's theorem, you should look at the logarithm : $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=\frac{1}{R}$ means clearly that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log |a_n|}{n} = -\log R$, hence for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$ : $\frac{\log |a_n|}{n} <-\log R+\epsilon$ when $n$ is large enough , hence $|a_n|<R^{-n}e^{n\epsilon}$ when $n$ is large enough, hence $\sum_{n= N}^\infty\frac{|a_n|}{e^{n\epsilon}R^{n}} z^n<\sum_{n=N}^\infty |z[^n$ which is known to converge when $|z| < 1$. i.e.  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges when $|z|<R$

Comment: @user1952009 The test referred to here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RootTest.aspx from regular calculus which actually does not require positive series terms. So now I am not sure I am incorrect unless somehow this goes wrong for complex series. I will upvote when I have understood.

Comment: I added the [abscissa of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Analytic_properties_of_Dirichlet_series:_the_abscissa_of_convergence) to my answer. tell me if there is something you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that since $A(n) = \sum_{k \le n} a_k$ is  bounded, then the [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges **at least for $Re(s) > 0$**.

By [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) : $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n n^{-s} = A(N) N^{-s} +\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s})$$ $$ =  A(N) N^{-s} +\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) \int_n^{n+1} s \, x^{-s-1}dx }_{\le   \sum_{n=1}^N C \,|s|\, |n^{-s-1}|} $$

This is a way to prove that the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ converges for $Re(s) > 0$.

---

Even more important : this is how we prove the [abscissa of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Analytic_properties_of_Dirichlet_series:_the_abscissa_of_convergence) that if a Dirichlet series converges at some $s_0$, then it converges for every $s, Re(s) > Re(s_0)$.

with $A_{s_0}(N) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n^{-s_0}$ :

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n^{-s_0} n^{-s+s_0} = A_{s_0}(N)N^{-s+s_0} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A_{s_0}(n) (n^{-s+s_0}-(n+1)^{-s+s_0})$$

. since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s_0}$ is supposed to converge, then $|A_{s_0}(n)|  < C$, and as before $|n^{-s+s_0}-(n+1)^{-s+s_0}| = |(s-s_0) \int_{n}^{n+1} x^{-s+s_0-1} dx | < |s-s_0| |n^{-s+s_0-1}|$ hence

$$|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n n^{-s}| < C | N^{-s+s_0}|+C\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n^{-Re(s-s_0)-1}$$

and it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N  a_n n^{-s}$ converges.

Comment: I understand this, but it seems overly complicated. The proof I provided also works and requires far less machinery.

Comment: @qbert : what ???  Come on read again. The answer is that it converges for $Re(s) > 0$, not only $Re(s) > 1$ !!

Comment: The nth root test is valid for complex series, I do not see how my proof is incorrect. Ah I see, because it converges to 1. Fair enough.

Comment: @qbert : because you would get that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ converges.  your proof is valid for showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges for $|z| < 1$.. not for showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges for $Re(s) > 1$

Comment: no, it would be valid for this series if the limit weren't one by the regular nth root test. I promise you I am not trying to apply Hadamard's to something that isn't a power series, just the regular nth root test.

Comment: @qbert : if $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} < 1$ then yes $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ would converge on $|z| = 1$, and hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ would converge for EVERY $s$ (it would be an entire Dirichlet series)

Comment: @qbert : if you had $\lim_n |a_n|^{1/n} < 1$ you would get that $|a_n n^{-s}| < C(1-\epsilon)^n$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and some constant $C$, and as usual $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty C (1-\epsilon)^n = \frac{C}{1-(1-\epsilon)}$

Answer (score 1):

If the question is as you say then it is simpler and the hint indeed seems to overcomplicate things (unless the exact question is *not that*):

$$\left|\frac{a_n}{n^s}\right|=\frac{|a_n|}{|n^s|}=\frac{|a_n|}{n^{\text{Re}\,s}}$$

so if  Re$\,s>1\;$ the comparison test gives us absolute convergence as $\;|a_n|\;$ is bounded.

Comment: you have to prove first that $a_n$ is bounded, which is indeed obvious since we are given $|\sum_{n =1}^k a_n| < C$ hence $|a_{k+1}| =|\sum_{n =1}^{k+1} a_n-\sum_{n =1}^k a_n| < 2C$

Comment: @19 Thank you. You mean **the asker** had to prove that, as it follows at once from the conditions. Yet you already did that for him.