# Showing that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln k}{k^s}$ converges for all $\Re s > 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln k/k^s$ converges for all $\Re s > 1$. Since $\ln k/k^\alpha\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ for all $\alpha > 0$, there exists a $N$ such that $\ln k<k^{\alpha}$ for all $k\geq N$ and all $\alpha>0$. Then 
$$\left | \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln k}{k^s} \right |\leq \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{\ln k}{k^{\Re s}}+\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\Re s-\alpha}},$$
on the right side, the first sum is finite, and the second sum converges for all $\Re s > 1+\alpha$. Letting $\alpha \to 0$, we are done. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: What does that script R and s mean?

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, yes, that is how you prove convergence of $\sum \ln n/n^s$. But you don't need to let $\alpha \to 0$ at all.  Assume an arbitrary $s$ and let $\alpha = s/2$.

Comment: what do you mean letting $a \to 0$ ? at first you have a fixed $s = 1+\epsilon + i T$ and it is enough to pick $a = \epsilon / 2$

Comment: @theakholic $\Re s$ means the real part of a complex value $s$. I am unsure about the conclusion. Since $\alpha$ was abitrary, I thought I could let it go $0$ to get the wished result.

Comment: Looks fine. Alternative way of finishing it up: if $\Re s > 1$ then take $\alpha = \frac{\Re s - 1}{2}$. For this value we have $\Re s > 1+\alpha > 1$ and your argument gives convergence for this value of $s$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks for the alternative conclusion! I'll borrow it :)

Comment: now you might also want to look at what I wrote there http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1805037/276986 that if a Dirichlet series converges at some $s_0$ then it converges for every $Re(s) > Re(s_0)$