# Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^n}$ converge for $\Re(n)=1,\Im(n)\ne0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, conditional-convergence

Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^n}$ converge for $\Re(n)=1,\Im(n)\ne0$?

The ratio test is inconclusive.

It passes the term test for $\Re(n)=1$, but this is not sufficient to prove convergence.

Since we are dealing with so many complex numbers, I do not know of any convergence tests for this.  I know that if it is convergent, it is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Strange notation, because $n$ is usually an integer.

Comment: @zhw. nah, $n\in\mathbb C$ here.

Comment: Yes I know, I was commenting on the strangeness of it.

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive for all series of the form  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(n^{x+iy}),$ with $x>0.$

Comment: @Winther I do not know if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-xi\ln(k)}$ is bounded.

Comment: You mean the partial sums of that series.

Comment: @SimpleArt One can directly see that this is not Cauchy.  The idea is that for $k^{1+it}$, doubling the value of $k$ only causes the phase to advance by $O(t)$.  So if we sum a range of the form $[k, k + \Theta(k/t)]$ then the phases of each term can be bounded to within a small interval.  The absolute values of these terms sum to $\Theta(1/t)$, which is bounded away from $0$ no matter how large $k$ is.  Thus the series is not Cauchy.

Comment: @ErickWong Could you provide link/reference?  And $O(t)$ refers to big-O notation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SimpleArt Almost the same question was already asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250470/conditional-convergence-of-riemanns-zetas-series

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks, very insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n^{-s} - \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s} dx = \int_n^{n+1} (n^{-s}-x^{-s}) dx = \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s y^{-s-1}dy dx = \mathcal{O}(s n^{-s-1})$$  so that 
$$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s} dx) &=& \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}- \int_1^{N+1}x^{-s}dx \\ &=& \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s} + \frac{(N+1)^{1-s}-1}{s-1}\underset{\qquad \scriptstyle (s \ne 1)}{}\end{eqnarray}$$
converges for $Re(s) > 0$.

Since $N^{1-s}$ diverges whenever $Re(s) \le 1$, so does $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$.

Note that by analytic continuation :
$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s} - \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s} dx)\qquad \quad (Re(s) > 0)$$

Comment: Are you saying that $\sum n^{-s}$ converges if $\sum n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1}x^{-s}dx$ converges?  I'm not sure, but at the very least, I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}x^{-s}dx$ diverges.  Just confused on why we got to that integral.

Comment: @SimpleArt no it is not what I said

Comment: Then how does it relate to the divergence/convergence of $\sum n^{-s}$?

Comment: I already know how to extend the Riemann zeta function to pretty much any value, but I'm just interested in that summation ^^

Comment: @SimpleArt honestly I wrote everything

Comment: Oh, so it is clear that $\sum n^{-s}-\int x^{-s}dx$ converges regardless of $s$, so it is merely a matter of whether $\int_1^{N+1}x^{-s}dx$ converges.  Did I get that right?  And thank you.

Comment: @SimpleArt your notations are horrible :) mines are correct : as $N \to \infty$, $\ \ (\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}) - \int_1^{N+1} x^{-s}dx$ converges for $Re(s) >0$

Comment: Sh... just short-handing.  These are the comments, and you get what I mean.

Comment: @SimpleArt now, do you understand the last line ?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.

Comment: @SimpleArt ok explain it

Comment: Well, since $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1}x^{-s}dx)$ converges for $\Re(s)>0$ and is equal to $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{-s}-\int_1^{N+1}x^{-s}dx$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converges if $\int_1^\infty x^{-s}dx$ converges, and the integral only converges for $\Re(s)>1$.  Note you can use \Re

Comment: @SimpleArt I meant the last line with the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ for $Re(s) > 0$

Comment: Oh, but that's quite frankly obvious, since the integral is equal to $1/(s-1)$ if it converges.  :/

Comment: @SimpleArt No. What is obvious is that $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s} -  \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx)$ is analytic on $Re(s) > 0$ (why ?), and since for $Re(s) > 1$ we have $(s-1)F(s) = (s-1)\zeta(s) - 1$, by [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) this stays true for $Re(s) > 0$.

Comment: (note that I didn't define $\zeta(s)$ for $Re(s) \in (0,1]$ yet, I just supposed it had an analytic continuation, that indeed I just proved. of course, using $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$, it also proves that $(1-2^{1-s})(F(s)(s-1)+1) = \eta(s)(s-1)$)

Comment: :/ well, that's not so obvious if you haven't taken Calc. II.  Um, yeah.  I just know that if $\zeta(s)$ is analytic and follows some functional equation that is analytic on a domain beyond the zeta function's original domain, then the analytic continuation of the zeta function must still follow that functional equation.  That's my best definition of analytic continuation so far.

Comment: @SimpleArt you should look at $\frac{1}{1-z}$ the analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, then at $\Gamma(s)$, and of course at a complex analysis course

Comment: Working towards that complex analysis course, and already know how to analytically continue the zeta and gamma function with some extremely bad notation and half-complete logic.  :/

Answer (score 1):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897433/convergence-of-zetas-on-res-1/1897815#1897815), I used the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula (EMSF) to show that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n}$ converges for $\text{Re}(n)>1$ and diverges for $\text{Re}(n)<1$.

Proceeding similarly, using the EMSF we can write for $n=1+iy$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^{1+iy}}&=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{e^{-iy\log(k)}}{k}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(y\log(N))}{y}+i\frac{\cos(y\log(N))}{y}+C+O\left(\frac1N\right)
\end{align}$$

for some constant $C$.

> Since both $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sin(y\log(N))$ and $\lim_{N\to \infty}\cos(y\log(N))$ diverge for $y\ne 0$, the series of interest diverges likewise.

Comment: How did you do the summation?

Comment: @martycohen Are you familiar with the EMSF?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to see the details rather than having to work them out myself.

Comment: There are few details.  The integral is trivial as is the asymptotic part.  The constant is not relevant here.