Convergence of Riemann zeta function
I am wondering whether the series $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$$ converges for $s$ with $\mathsf{Re}(s)=1$ and $\mathsf{Im}(s) \neq 0$. Note that I use the representation of $\zeta$ as an infinite sum, which converges absolutely if $\mathsf{Re}(s)>1$. For $\mathsf{Re}(s)=1$, the absolute values of the summands are the harmonic series, so the series does not converge absolutely. But does it converge conditionally? I tried to plot the partial sums in the complex plane and it looks as they lie on a circle or on a very slow spiral.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250470/conditional-convergence-of-riemanns-zetas-series and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84097/divergence-of-dirichlet-series

it is fairly straightforward to show that $\sum_{n \le x}n^{-s} = \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+o(1)$ for large enough $x$ (depending on $\Im s$, eg $x \ge |\Im s|$ will do) when $\Re s >0, s \ne 1$ so for a fixed $\Re s =1, s \neq 1$ the partial sums are bounded but oscillate and do not converge
